# Passing Command Arugments with textChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am very new to .net, so please bear with me.  I have a gridview that has a textbox and a label in each row.  The textbox displays the sort id number that the user can change.  The function I wrote that actually performs the changes needs two things passed to it in order to work.  The first is the new sort id number, which is easy enough to get from the textchanged event.  The second item it needs is the value of the label next to the changed text box.  I know things like LinkButton have a CommandArgument option, and I don't think textchanged events do.  Is there any way to get this information using gridview or some other method?  Here is the code for the text itself:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="OrderNum" runat="server" Width="25px" Text='<%#Eval("Order")%>' OnTextChanged='OrderChange'  ToolTip="Change Default Order" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: if this doesn't make much sense I can try to clear it up :/

Answer (score 0):

Finally Got this figured out if anyone else was having an issue with this.

```
TextBox box = ((TextBox)(sender));
string CountryCode=((Label)box.Parent.FindControl("CountryCode")).Text;
```